# What is the book series where people become "Forged"?

Tags: story-identification

It's been a really long time since I've read this series.  It's a fantasy series (don't remember author or title).  If I recall correctly, it's a world where there are several plot lines set.

In any case, the part I remember is that there are some invaders that rape and pillage and "Forge" the locals and afterwords they cannot remember who they are, no higher intellectual behavior, just pure instinct and savagery.

Can anyone name the series and/or author?

Comment: On a slight tangent, there is a space opera by Justina Robson called Natural History where humans take on new forms through the use of genetics and cybernetics and are known as the Forged.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The Farseer Trilogy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/055357339X) by Robin Hobb should be the series you are looking for.

There are a couple of other series by Hobb in the same world, including [The Rain Wilds Chronicles](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061561657), [The Liveship Traders](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553575635),  and [The Tawny Man](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553582445).

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I actually have that series on my shelf, just haven't read it in half a decade.  I also have the Liveship Traders (which I love) and the new Rain Wild Chronicles books on my To-Read shelf.  Appreciate it!